# What does this class/template usage mean in Java?

Tags: java, class, reflection

```
package MyTest;

import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class CallingMethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String firstName = new String("Deepak");
        String lastName = new String("Kumar");
        String result = new String("");

        Class<String> cls = String.class;
        Class[] parametertype = new Class[] { String.class };
        Object[] arguments = new Object[] { lastName };
        try {
            Method concatMethod = cls.getMethod("concat", parametertype);
            result = (String) concatMethod.invoke(firstName, arguments);
            System.out.println(" Concatenated String is => " + result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

For the above code, I don't understand below parts.

```
Class<String> cls = String.class;
Class[] parametertype = new Class[] { String.class };
Object[] arguments = new Object[] { lastName };
```

So what does `String.class` mean?
And `String.class` in `new Class[] { String.class }` means what? It means the first item in the array is a `String.class` type? Or all the items are `String.class` type?
And `new Object[] { lastName }`? It means the first item/instance of the array is lastName?
Hope to get your expertise! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what does String.class mean?

A reference to the String Class

> And String.class in new Class[] { String.class } means what?

An array of Classes which has one reference to the String Class.

> means the first item in the array is a String.class type?

The type of the first element is Class or `Class<String>`

> And new Object[] { lastName }? It means the first item/instance of the array is lastName?

Yes.

> I don't understand below parts.

It appears you are correct in all your questions so it appears you were right all along.

Do you have any other questions?

Comment: I am a newbie to Java, but I feel interesting of these concepts. I am not sure of my answers, so ask here. Really thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The code is using reflection and method invocation to call the `concat` method in the `String` class, on the object `firstName`, using the arguments parameters. It is similar to calling:

```
result = firstName.concat(lastName);
```

Answer (score 1):

- `Class<String> cls = String.class;` is a [Class object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) which refers to the String class.
- `Class[] parametertype = new Class[] { String.class };` is an array of Class objects, containing one element: `String.class`
- `Object[] arguments = new Object[] { lastName };` is an array of Objects containing one element too

Answer (score 1):

Every object in Java is associated with a *type*, e.g., *String* or *MyClass*. The *type* is itself implemented by another object. So *String.class* and *MyClass.class* are referring to the class objects for those types.